# Update modified Shopify third-party theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme, updates, e-commerce

I bought a Shopify third-party theme and I have added some script changes for customization and functionalities.

What is the best practice to update a modified Shopify third-party theme without losing the previous changes and breaking my website?

Comment: I don't know about Shopify, I know how WordPress themes work. You have always a chance to create a Child Theme to modify a parent theme's feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying third-party themes should be avoided in the first place. [Creating a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) is the proper way to customize a third-party theme because it allows for the parent theme to be updated without worrying about having your customizations overwritten when updating. Being able to update is important for security and it's nice to be able to have the latest features and bug fixes.

Since the Shopify theme has already been modified, here are the steps that you can take to get a child theme up and running and update your parent theme.

1. Make a backup copy of your modified parent theme and set it aside for safe keeping.
2. Create a basic child theme [using the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) for the modified third-party theme and activate it.
3. Port your modifications over to the child theme.
4. Replace the modified Shopify theme with the newly updated version.
5. Test to ensure that everything is working properly.

Comment: You got it, ablevf!